# Javascript Google Classroom API

Tags: javascript, google-classroom

I'm trying to access the Google Classroom API with Javascript and am running into a syntax problem when trying to create a student.

The relevant code is

```
  function createStudent () {
     var course_id = '146694xxx'
     var enrollment_code = '7ytxxx'
     var student = {
        userId: 'xxx@gmail.com'
    }
    student = gapi.client.classroom.courses.students.create({courseId:course_id,enrollmentCode:enrollment_code, params: student}).execute();
}
```

The problem is with the named parameter for the student object. It is where I have "params". I have tried every name I can think of like requestBody, body and a million others. The error I get is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"params\" at 'student': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "student",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"params\" at 'student': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How should I be representing that request body object in the call?

Thanks.

Harry

Comment: I think you are looking for the [Method: courses.students.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create). The request body is specified [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students#Student).

Comment: Thanks.Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. What I'm having problems with is how to express the student object in the Javascript create method call as the request body. In most other Google API calls, the request body is preceded with requestBody:. That doesn't work here. That's what has me baffled.